# Using wait() instead of waitpid() within a while loop

Tags: c, wait, zombie-process, waitpid

I know that one of the differences between wait() and waitpid() is that waitpid having a WNOHANG option which tells the waitpid not to block if there are running children that have not yet terminated. Such as:

```
while (  (pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    printf("Child %d terminated\n", pid);
```

If I use wait() instead of waitpid(), there is no way to prevent wait() from blocking if there are running children that have not yet terminated. However, I wonder if wait() works fine here, even though it may block.

Comment: That loop will only loop as long as there are processed being terminated. Otherwise if no child processes have terminated, it will only cause one call to `waitpid`, which returns `0` and breaks out of the loop.

Comment: If I put this code into a signal handler(catching the SIGCHLD signal), which excutes because there is a child have terminated, will wait() works fine?

Comment: If you received a `SIGCHLD` signal, you _know_ something happened with a child process, and therefore can call `wait` without it blocking.

Comment: If there are many children processes, some have terminated but some have not, can I use such a wait() handler?

Comment: Then you should use the loop you have in your question.

Comment: Never use `wait()`; it's an obsolete API with several problems. If there are two places in your code where you create children, `wait()` can reap the wrong pid (this is a bug for example in old implementations of `system()`). There's rarely any reason not to `waitpid()` for the process you're actually interested in and keep things clean.

Answer (score -2):

we cannot call **wait** in a loop, because there is no way to prevent **wait** from blocking if there are running children that have not yet terminated.